# How can I combine two nodecollection?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I got

```
var x =  document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("*//tr[@class='even']")
var y = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("*//tr[@class='odd']")
```

How can I combine these html node collections?

### Edit:

gonna try `x.Concat(y).ToList()`

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?  It will most likely make a difference on the best method to get your actual need.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I guess .concat did work. I wanted to use it like foreach (HtmlNode node in combinednodes) { var name =node.SelectSingleNode("*//a[@class='cellMainLink']").InnerText;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is using XPath approach. You can use XPath union (`|`) to combine two queries :

```
var xy = document.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("*//tr[@class='even'] | *//tr[@class='odd']");
```