# How to combine node collections?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

there is a question [How can I combine two nodecollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411107/how-can-i-combine-two-nodecollection)  which is about combining two collections.

I want to set it like

```
         var sas=(HtmlNodeCollection) null;
```

then use

```
        sas+=ca.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong");
```

is this possible?

Comment: No, you can't define `+` for existing types... Depending one what you want to do there could be ways around (i.e. similar to Artyom Kharlamov's answer ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ method concat (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var nodeEnum = sas.Concat(ca.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong"))
```

But you must initialize sas first as an empty HtmlNodeCollection.

Comment: thanks. I need to combine them like 200 times. I mean I need something like                                                                                                      var nodes=ca.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong");
                allnodes= sas.Concat(allnodes);                but It gives the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection'.            How can I cast them?

Comment: I needed to define List<HtmlNode> allnodes = new List<HtmlNode>();

Comment: Yes, as a result of COncat you get IEnumerable<HtmlNode>. So you need to make: IEnumerable<HtmlNode> sas=(HtmlNodeCollection) null; and then work with IEnumerable. But I highly recommend you to change design cause Concat is pretty slow operation (not concat but enumaration of enumerable). If you provide more details about your problem I can advice you something.